# Reditect the jil error output to log file

Tags: ksh, io-redirection, autosys

I am using autosys 11.3..

I have created one *.ksh* file and one *jil* file like below:

### .KSH file(test.ksh):

```
echo "test"
```

### .jil file(test.jil)

```
insert_job: test11   job_type: CMD
machine: ravi
owner: rchalla
std_out_file: /export/home/rchalla/test.out
std_err_file: /export/home/rchalla/test.err
```

When I execute the above *jil* file I see this error:

```
$ jil < test.jil > test1.log
CAUAJM_E_18936 Required JIL keyword "command" is missing.
CAUAJM_E_10302 Database Change WAS NOT successful.
CAUAJM_E_50198 Exit Code = 1
```

But this error is not redirecting to test1.log file.

Can anybody please me what is the process to redirect the executed jil error log to log file?

Answer (score 2):

To redirect error output to file you need either to redirect std err (2) to std out (1):

```
jil < test.jil >test1.log 2>&1
```

or explicitly specify that you are redirecting std err (2):

```
jil < test.jil 2>test1.log
```

or redirect outputs to different files:

```
jil < test.jil >stdout.log 2>stderr.log
```